# How to send only raw value in HTTP request in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, http

I want to perform a put request in Java Spring using `rest template`. I know how to do a regular request where the value looks like a traditional JSON:

```
{
    "key":"value"
}
```

however i want to send the data as raw value:

```
foobar
```

At least in Postman that is what the data looks like in the raw option

How can this be emulated in Spring?

**EDIT**: Additional Info

Here is the code that I am currently using

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response =
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, createHttpEntity(), String.class);
```

`createHttpEntity()` adds headers with appropriate authorization etc

The URL consumes a PUT request and accepts a singular link like so:

```
https://foobar.com
```

```
public HttpEntity createHttpEntity()
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(Constants.AUTHORIZATION, Constants.BEARER + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(token.getBytes()));
        headers.set(Constants.APP_ID_NAME, Constants.APP_ID);
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new HttpEntity( headers);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to call another webservice using a raw value, or accept/use a raw value in your webservice?

Comment: Could you post the code that uses the `RestTemplate`

Comment: Do you want to consume a REST service or expose one ?

Comment: added some additional info, please check

Comment: You should add the details of your HttpEntity creation, it's there that you define your request body

Comment: I added it, please take a look

Comment: @DanielJomaa Thanks,there's another constructor available, check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Content-Type:text/plain` in order to send plain text as a raw value in a request.

Original (wrong) answer:

Return a String (or whatever type of value you want to return) and annotate your method with @ResponseBody

Comment: I am trying to perform a put request, not consume one, similar to postman but using Rest Template

Comment: Does `createHttpEntity()` set the `Content-Type:text/plain` header?

Comment: It sets it to Content-Type application/json.

Comment: thanks, one more thing, how would i add the raw value to the body of the request?

Comment: When creating an `HttpEntity` you can set a body through its constructor along with the headers, it is the `HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this constructor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html#HttpEntity-T-org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap-) for your HttpEntity instead.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
// ...
return new HttpEntity<>("MY REQUEST BODY", headers);
```